# Найти минимум в массиве в диапазоне индексов

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Мне необходимо найти минимум в массиве в диапазоне индексов. 
 Вот мой код, но я не уверен правильно ли я его написал. прошу помочь

```
class MinDiapason {
    static int findMin(int[] array, int start, int finish) {
        var min = array[start];
        for (var i = start; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i < array[start]) {
                min = finish;
                break;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

Comment: нет, неправильно, прочитайте его построчно вникая в каждую строку, напишите комментарий для каждой строки, тогда скорее всего поймёте ошибки

Comment: не помогло :) ошибка видимо в условии, можно подсказку? только не само решение!!!

Comment: там много ошибок и непонятно что такое start и finish, неправильный if, там вы сравниваете текущий индекс с ?первым элементом массива?, min = finish очевидно тоже неправильно

Comment: start - индекс с которого начинаем поиск, finish - индекс которым заканчиваем поиск.
так я нахожу минимальное значение в массиве и возвращаю его:

static int findMin(int[] array, int start, int finish) {
        var min = array[start];
        for (int value : array) {
            if (value < min) {
                min = value;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

а мне надо чтобы  был найден минимальный элемент в границах int start  int finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ладно, вот решение

```
class MinDiapason {
    static int findMin(int[] array, int start, int finish) {
        var min = array[start];
        for (var i = start+1; i < finish; i++) {
            var value = array[i];
            if (value < min) {
                min = value;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

Comment: была ошибка в коде, поправил

Comment: спасибо. Единственный момент который я добавил это (**<=**):
    for (var i = start+1; i **<=** finish; i++)"

Answer (score 0):

```
class MinDiapason {    
    static Integer findMin(int[] array, int start, int finish) {
        Integer minNumber = null;
        for (int numbAray : array) {
            if (start<=numbAray && numbAray<finish && 
                    (minNumber==null || minNumber>numbAray)) minNumber = numbAray;
        }
        return minNumber;
    }
}
```